# How to create two buttons: when one is pushed other goes up

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

How to create two buttons: one button is pushed other goes up. I tried using this:

```
//Create male/female button objects
var maleButton:maleButtonObejct = new maleButtonObject();
var femaleButton:femaleButtonObject = new femaleButtonObject();

//Add evnet listeners to both buttons
maleButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, setToMale);
femaleButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, setToFemale);

//Create isMale variable
var isMale:Boolean;

//Male/Female button functions
function setToMale(event:MouseEvent):void  {
isMale = true;
maleButton.stop(3);
femaleButton.stop(1);
}

function setToFemale(event:MouseEvent):void  {
isMale = false;
femaleButton.stop(3);
maleButton.stop(1);
}
```

I get runtime error: **TypeError: Error #1006: stop is not a function.
    at Untitled_fla::MainTimeline/setToFemale()**

Comment: Do `maleButtonObject` and `femaleButtonObject` (all class names should be capitalized, by the way) extend `MovieClip`? Unless I am mistaken, MovieClip is the only class that has a `stop()` method. Your error says that either maleButton or femaleButton does not have a stop method, so that is your issue.

Comment: plus, I think you want to use `gotoAndStop` as `stop` doesn't take parameters

Comment: I removed the Flex tag as you do not seem to be using Flex in your samples here.  If you are using Flex; you can use a ToggleButton and the selectedState property to unpress on button while the other is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Rename your classes starting with a capital letter, such as MaleButton.

Here is an easy way to accomplish what you want:

```
var maleButton:MaleButton = new MaleButton();
var femaleButton:FemaleButton = new FemaleButton();

maleButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clicked);
maleButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clicked);

function clicked(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    switch(event.target)
    {
        case maleButton:
            maleButton.gotoAndStop(3);
            femaleButton.gotoAndStop(1);
            break;
        case femaleButton:
            maleButton.gotoAndStop(1);
            femaleButton.gotoAndStop(3);
            break;
        default:
            return;
    }   
}
```